# CSS & HTML Button Under each other adding text in between

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create 2 buttons with different links and have the second button be a clickable image. For some reason the text in between the buttons acts as a hyperlink. How do I fix this?

```css
.button1 {
  background-color: #E44040;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button2 {
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.button2 {
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<body style="font-family: arial">
  <p>Click the button below For youtube</p>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" method="get" target="_blank">
      <button class="button button1">Youtube</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Click the button below fork Reddit</p>
    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/" method="get" target="_blank">
      <button class="button button2" style="border: 0; background: transparent">
        <img src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/reddit-icon-reddit-logo-transparent-115628752708pqmsy4kgm.png" width="90" height="90"></button>
  </div>
```

Comment: close 'a' tag for each 'a'

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the a tags. Try this:

*Edit: changed the buttons to divs, see comment of user cloned.*

```css
body {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #E44040;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}  
  
.button2 {
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}
.button1 {border-radius: 2px;}
.button2 {border-radius: 12px;}
```

```html
<p>Click the button below For youtube</p>
<div>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" method="get" target="_blank">
        <div class="button button1">Youtube</div>
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Click the button below fork Reddit</p>
    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/" method="get" target="_blank">
        <div class="button button2" style="border: 0; background: transparent">
            <img src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/reddit-icon-reddit-logo-transparent-115628752708pqmsy4kgm.png" width="90" height="90">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't wrap a button with an a-tag, this does not make any sense from a semantic view. Either use one or the other

Comment: user cloned is right, consider changing the buttons to divs. (Keep the classes on the divs.)

Answer (score -1):

You have not closed the `<a>` tag.

This is the corrected code:

```css
.button1 {
  background-color: #E44040;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}  
 
.button2 {
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
 
}
.button1 {border-radius: 2px;}
.button2 {border-radius: 12px;}
```

```html
<body style="font-family: arial">
        <p>Click the button below For youtube</p>
    <div>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" method="get" target="_blank">
        <button class="button button1">Youtube</button>
       </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Click the button below fork Reddit</p>
        <a href="https://www.reddit.com/" method="get" target="_blank">
        <button class="button button2" style="border: 0; background: transparent">
        <img src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/reddit-icon-reddit-logo-transparent-115628752708pqmsy4kgm.png" width="90" height="90">
        </button>
      </a>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: The a-tags are empty and have collapsed to 0 (zero) height and are thus unclickable.

Comment: Edited the above changes